# At what number do my free ports start and till what number?

Tags: networking, firewall, port

I need to configure ports in my firewall. My external ip starts with 75, my local ip starts with 192. At what number do my free ports start and till what number ?

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve. Available ports are in no way related to your IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers);

The port numbers are divided into three ranges: the Well Known Ports,
the Registered Ports, and the Dynamic and/or Private Ports.

The Well Known Ports are those from 0 through 1023.

DCCP Well Known ports SHOULD NOT be used without IANA registration.
The registration procedure is defined in [RFC4340], Section 19.9.

The Registered Ports are those from 1024 through 49151

DCCP Registered ports SHOULD NOT be used without IANA registration.
The registration procedure is defined in [RFC4340], Section 19.9.

The Dynamic and/or Private Ports are those from 49152 through 65535

Comment: Yes i know that. But do ports differ from type A to C class IP ?

Comment: I have static private network

Comment: i used ports from 10000 to 20000 and download worked on all programs, just upload was strange on some.

Comment: anyway, i'll try from 50000 up and see.

Comment: The port ranges are not related to the ip address. All TCP hosts use the same port ranges regardless of their ip address. A TCP connection (or session) is made up of what's called a 4-Tuple: source ip address and port<->destination ip address and port. It doesn't matter if the ip address is public, private, or NAT'ed.

Comment: thank you dbasnett & joeqwerty for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad to pitch in.